# Password accepted by passwd but not su

Tags: centos, ssh, passwd

The passwords on one of my CentOS boxes is no longer accepted by `ssh` or `su` for the user clipuser but that same password is accepted by `passwd` (after su'ing from root to the user).

/var/log/secure doesn't really have anything useful, here is the relevant log entries:

```
Feb 21 16:58:37 CLIP sshd[2448]: pam_tally3(sshd:auth): user clipuser (500) tally 31, deny 3
Feb 21 16:58:39 CLIP sshd[2448]: Failed password for clipuser from 172.16.66.239 port 33928 ssh2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like your clipuser account has been locked by the pam_tally module. You either have to wait for the unlock timer to expire, or manually run the `pam_tally --reset` command.

If that happened, then it can only be one thing: The password you used to login was not the password you set with `passwd` or you made a typo more than 3 times (or whatever the pam_tally retry count limit is set to in your pam.conf file).

You can do a `man pam.conf` to see more details about the config, or `man pam_tally` to read more on the command itself.

Comment: +1 -- Also, I believe "tally 31, deny 3" means it has been entered incorrectly 31 times, and it is set to fail after 3 times.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem, I must've entered the password wrong multiple times (very likely) although I was entering it correctly by the time I posted the question. I wish the pam tally question was more clear.

Comment: Also on this computer I need to run `pam_tally3` instead of just `pam_tally`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your ssh config is blocking remote access for root and su is probably doing something similar locally. Double check all your configs.

Comment: No, I'm trying to login as a regular user, not root.